# Replace relative URL within sveltekit a href with another

Tags: sveltekit

I have a site with my file structure as so:

[image]

I am paginating results.  Navigating to dashboard/page/1 will show the first ten results.  When I click on one of the results, I would like the url to bring me to article/category/.../sub6.

I would just put the article folder after my [pagenum], but since the pagenum is dynamic it will change when new data is eventually added, in addition to removing the ability to have filtered, paginated results (I am assuming).

How can I have the a href send me to a different branch within my routing scheme?  Is that possible?  If not, how do people handle this scenario with sveltekit?

Edit for clarity:  My href is on the /page/[pagenum] page, so when I click it to go to the article route it prepends that route with the /page/[pagenum] route, which is not what I want.  I want the url for the link to the article to not be prepended with the page/[pagenum] route.

Comment: Simply use absolute URLs that match the chosen path, i.e. `href="/article/category/subcategory/sub3/sub4/sub5/sub6"`, or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear enough in my question.  My href is on the /page/[pagenum] page, so when I click it to go to the article route it prepends that route with the /page/[pagenum] route, which is not what I want.

Comment: That was my point, if you use absolute URLs (with a leading slash) rather than relative ones (*without* a leading slash) as you appear to be using, the path will be set from the root of your domain (which corresponds to the base of the `/src/routes` directory in your project) rather than from the current page.

Comment: Wow, it was really that simple.  Thank you!

Does this exist anywhere in the documentation?

Comment: Not really, relative (to the current document) vs. absolute (= relative to the root of a website domain) URLs is more of a basic HTML notion, this is not specific to SvelteKit. It just happpens that using absolute paths is the solution to your problem ;)